# how to fix no module named "wmi" in python

Tags: python, networking, wmi

I have a python script that deal with internal network  and for that i need to import **wmi module**
witch i install it on offline mode using the **.whl** extension. 
I have **Windows7 64 bit** so i downloaded the below package .

```
python -m pip install pywin32-227-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

When i do `pip freeze` and show that the **pywin32 ==227** is installed but when i run the script and crash and display the below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "wmi"
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Install wmi? E.g. `pip install wmi`. `pywin32` is another module.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yes but its offline  so i must installed without connected to the internet

Comment: So you have to download [the wheel](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/#files) first.

Comment: i searched about package to deal with network and windows server so all the googling  result to instal pywin32  isn't the write package?

Comment: Did you check the wmi package, as in my link above?

Comment: i downloaded the whl  and its on my local drive and it did installed as it display on pip freeze

Comment: So does it work now? I'm not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: i am trying to download it and install it  i will let you know if it works thank you